# Banach spaces containing copies of $\ell^1$

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces, motivation

Why is it important that a Banach spaces $X$ contains (or not) copies of the space $\ell^1$? I always hear talk about it but I don't know its importance.

Could someone explain this?

Comment: I believe it is a legitimate question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Containing $\ell^1$ implies that the space

1. Is non-reflexive (since a subspace of a reflexive space is also reflexive)
2. Has trivial type (=1), I won't go into details here.
3. Has  nonseparable dual, since the dual of a subspace is a quotient of dual, and $(\ell^1)^*$ is nonseparable.

If you are interested in the geometry of Banach spaces, these are pretty interesting things to know about a space. If you are not, you can live your life without ever worrying about it.

Comment: Is there an easy counterexample to the converse of the first statement? That's: if $X$ is not reflexive then $X$ doesn't contain copies of $\ell_1$.

Comment: You didn't state the converse correctly, but an example is $c_0$. It's a nonreflexive space whose dual ($\ell^1$) is separable. Therefore, $c_0$ does not contain $\ell^1$.

Answer (score 6):

I would say that it is important because of the [Rosenthal's $\ell_1$-theorem](http://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007%2F978-1-4612-5200-9_12#page-1) which asserts that

> Given a bounded sequence in a Banach space, it either contains a basic subsequence equivalent to a basis for $\ell_1$ or a weakly Cauchy subsequence.

Thus, if a space $X$ does not contain copies of $\ell_1$ all bounded sequences in $X$ have weakly Cauchy subsequences which is a nice and useful compactness-like statement. Note that we don't make any assumptions on $X$ whatsoever!

Comment: Viz. [my question here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4382757/815585) on basic subsequences, this $\ell_1$-theorem is very important in resolving my confusion. If it's not too much trouble, could you perhaps explain what your definition of basic subsequence is? I think $\{x_n\}$ is considered a basis subsequence if every element of $y\in\overline{\operatorname{span}\{x_n:n\in\Bbb N\}}$ is expressible as a finite linear combination from $x_n$. Is this right? And the basis for $\ell_1$ is just a Hamel basis, yes?

Comment: @FShrike, a basic sequence is a sequence that is a Schauder basis for its closed linear span, no Hamel bases involved. The standard basis of $\ell_1$ comprises sequences that are null besides the $n$th place, where they assume 1.